# ZeroDivisionError in the eval function for hub.compute when kept a default value of 1 for the num_workers parameter

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, data-science, hub

I was using [Hub the Dataset format for AI](https://github.com/activeloopai/hub) and I ran `function().eval(ds.tensor[:].numpy(), ds` which gave me a zero division error.

However when I ran `function().eval(ds.tensor[:].numpy(), ds, num_workers=2)` I did not get the error.

I was using Hub version: 2.2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for `num_workers` is 0, which is referenced in the [Hub source code](https://github.com/activeloopai/Hub/blob/6c2033ad36e2025676e07a6752df0168087ab0a3/hub/core/transform/transform.py#L78). So, I believe the problem is that you set the `eval` function to a default value of 1 rather than 0.

The [MNIST Dataset](https://docs.activeloop.ai/datasets/mnist#train-a-model-on-mnist-dataset-with-pytorch-in-python) docs showcase how you can set the num_workers to the default value of 0.